# when i Use MySQL Database System with Jena2,i got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: mysql, jena

here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.DBConnection;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.IDBConnection;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelMaker;

public class myontoly {

     public static final String MYSQL_DB_CLASSNAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";



        public static final String MYSQL_DB_URL =

           "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8";



        public static final String MYSQL_DB_USER = "root";



        public static final String MYSQL_DB_PASSWD = "mysql2011510";



        public static final String DB = "MySQL";



        public static void main(String[] args) {

           //     loading the JDBC driver

           try {

               Class.forName(MYSQL_DB_CLASSNAME).newInstance();

           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block

               e.printStackTrace();

           } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



           //Create database connection

           IDBConnection conn = new DBConnection(MYSQL_DB_URL, MYSQL_DB_USER, MYSQL_DB_PASSWD, DB);

           //Use the connection to create a model maker

           ModelMaker maker = ModelFactory.createModelRDBMaker(conn);

           Model base = maker.createDefaultModel();



           FileInputStream inputStreamfile = null;

           File file = new File("file:./Taxonomy.owl");

           try {

               inputStreamfile = new FileInputStream(file);

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block

               e1.printStackTrace();

           }

           InputStreamReader in = null;

           try {

               in =new InputStreamReader(inputStreamfile, "UTF-8");

           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block

               e1.printStackTrace();

           }

           base.read(in, null);

           try {

               in.close();

           } catch (IOException e1) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block

               e1.printStackTrace();

           }

           base.commit();

           //Close the database connection

           try {

               conn.close();

           } catch (SQLException e) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block

               e.printStackTrace();

           }
        }}
```

the error information,,and i tried jena 2.4,  2.6.4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createModelRDBMaker(Lcom/hp/hpl/jena/db/IDBConnection;)Lcom/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelMaker;
    at com.webservicecom.mysql.myontoly.main(myontoly.java:71))

Answer (score 1):

That's a very old version of Jena. Please try again with the latest version from the [current Jena distribution](http://jena.apache.org/download/index.html).

Comment: I had tried lateat version jena2.10,but I cant find jana.jar package.

Comment: when I import the jars of jena 2.10 's lib folder, it shows wrong, because it did't recognize the DBConnection.please test the code,and show me how can i fix it

Comment: The old RDB database layer was deprecated and removed sometime ago.  There are two persistent layers: SDB (over SQL databases) and TDB (custom native database).  TDB is faster and scales better.

Comment: Hah, I didn't even notice that the OP's code was using RDB not SDB.