# I want to persist the RDF model in MySql using Jena

Tags: java, mysql, rdf, jena

```
package rdf;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.DBConnection;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.IDBConnection;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelMaker;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.PrintUtil;

public class DbModelTester {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static final String RDF_FILE = "http://www.liyangyu.com/foaf.rdf";
public static final String ONTOLOGY_FILE = "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/";
private static String className = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myFoafModel";
private static String DB_USER = "root";
private static String DB_PASSWD = "passwd";
private static String DB_TYPE = "MySQL";
private static String DOCUMENT_NAME = "myFoafRDF";
private static String ONTOLOGY_NAME = "foaf.owl";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    IDBConnection conn = null;
    ModelMaker maker = null;
    try{
        Class.forName(className);
        conn = new DBConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_TYPE);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    maker = ModelFactory.createModelRDBMaker(conn);
    Model m = null;
    if ( !maker.hasModel(DOCUMENT_NAME) == true ) {
        System.out.println( "Loading instance document - one time only" );
        m = maker.createModel(DOCUMENT_NAME);
        FileManager.get().readModel(m,RDF_FILE);
    } else {
        m = maker.getModel(DOCUMENT_NAME);
    }
    printStatements(m, null, null, null);

    // close the connection
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
private static void printStatements(Model m, Resource s, Property p, Resource o) {
    for (StmtIterator i = m.listStatements(s,p,o); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Statement stmt = i.nextStatement();
        System.out.println(" - " + PrintUtil.print(stmt));
    }
}
}
```

When I run this code I am getting this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method createModelRDBMaker(IDBConnection) is undefined for the type ModelFactory
at rdf.DbModelTester.main(DbModelTester.java:41)

I want to persist the RDF model in MySql using Jena.
I am using latest version of Jena (apache-jena-2.11.1) and using MySql 5.5.

Comment: After adding the this (jena-2.6.0.jar) jar file in my project above exception is removed. I can see the tables which are created in my MySql database but now it is throwing a new exception                  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/iri/IRIFactory
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.ARPOptions.<clinit>(ARPOptions.java:60)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.<init>(XMLHandler.java:367)

Comment: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/iri/IRIFactory " You probably need more jars.  2.6.0 is rather old; Jena's up to 2.11 at the moment.  Are you including *all* the jars from the Jena distribution?  You should include them all.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor , I am using the latest version of Jena (2.11) and already included all the jar files of this version. But after getting the first Exception which I have mentioned in my post I added one more jar (jena-2.6.0.jar). After my first Exception is solved now I am getting this (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/iri/IRIFactory) exception.

Comment: Ah, here we are: have a look at [when i Use MySQL Database System with Jena2,i got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16171914/1281433), in which @AndyS comments, "The old RDB database layer was deprecated and removed sometime ago. There are two persistent layers: SDB (over SQL databases) and TDB (custom native database). TDB is faster and scales better. –  AndyS Apr 25 '13 at 9:01"  You should look into using [SDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/) if you need to use an SQL database.

Comment: To agree with @jousua-taylor -- "com.hp.hpl.jena.db.DBConnection" If you managing to compile code with that in, you have version of Jena on the build time classpath.  You can't use 2.6.0 and 2.11 at the same time.