# Apache Jena Core - What happend to Reifier interface in version 2.10?

Tags: jena

I was in the process of trying to update my Jena code to a more recent version (currently using 2.6.4). I wanted to use 2.11 but I realized that the Reifier interface is gone in that version. Why was it deprecated and is there an alternative that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: "Why was it deprecated and is there an alternative that I can use?"  The first part isn't a general technical question that anyone can answer;  you'd need to check the development mailing lists and communicate with the developers. They're friendly, though. Check the list archives first, and if you don't find an answer, ask on the list.  You can make this question more specific by showing the code that worked in the previous version and asking about what you can to do make it work with 2.11.

Comment: The tag wiki entry for [tag:apache] says "The Apache HTTP Server, commonly referred to as Apache, is an open-source HTTP server for modern operating systems including UNIX, its variants and Windows. Apache is a secure, efficient and extensible server that provides HTTP services in sync with the current HTTP standards."  This isn't about that.  I've removed the tag.

Comment: Duplicated at answers.semanticweb.com at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/28682/apache-jena-core-what-happened-to-reifier-interface-in-version-210.

Comment: According to some [javadoc on Reifier uses](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~hideaki/man/Jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/class-use/Reifier.html), it looks like it was only used in the database interoperability stuff.  The switch to TDB and SDB might explain its removal.  E.g., see the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/q/23930528/1281433.

Comment: Now that makes sense. Thanks Joshua. We are getting rid of the database functionality and replacing it with TDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around. I found the answer. 
http://t5623.apache-jena-development.apacheforum.info/jena-core-simplification-t5623.html